# How can you change the iCloud account name on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, icloud, email

Is there any way to change the iCloud account name (not the actual email address, just the name of the account as in System Preferences/Internet Accounts on macOS) on iOS?

I know this had been possible in the past, but I can't find the setting anymore.