# Change iCloud account name in iPhone Mail app

Tags: iphone, icloud, mail.app, email

Version: iOS 17.1.2

This was already posted at [How can you change the iCloud account name on iOS 10?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281383/how-can-you-change-the-icloud-account-name-on-ios-10) but the answer didn't help.

I'm looking for a way to change my iCloud account name in my iPhone's Mail app:

[image: Screenshot of the iPhone's Mail Accounts settings]

I've set my name everywhere I could find and still, it displays the name "iCloud".

Comment: Your link is to the screenshot, not another post

Comment: @Ezekiel fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't edit these names, the names you see in *Settings > Mail > Accounts* correspond to the name of the service your email is from. You can have: Gmail, iCloud, Exchange and many others.